# Odd change detection behavior Angular 2+

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I am working on a big application and I am having some issues with change detection.

**Parent Component ts:**

Using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

I have a variable that is an observable

`loaderOverlay$: Observable<boolean>;`

```
this.loaderOverlay$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(selectors.loaderOverlaySelector)
);
```

This variable gets updated from an rxjs action from a child component. Then goes through the rxjs process. (Action -> Reducer -> Selector)

**Parent Component HTML**

`<div *ngif="(loaderOverlay$ | async)"></div>`

Child #1 Component (where I'm dispatching my action):

```
myFunction() {
  this.store.dispatch(new actions.LoaderOverlay(true));
}
```

---

My issue is that once I dispatch the action, the `*ngif` is very shaky. It doesn't seem to work the way I want it to (dispatch the action, change the value to true so the div appears). It's very strange because if I `console.log(action.payload)` in the reducer, the value is actually being updated, but the `*ngif` isn't working. And what's even stranger is when I hover over some other component, it seems to kick in.

I think I've narrowed it down to change detection because in the parent component if I do:

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
   this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

It seems to work for me. My issue with this is that `ngAfterViewChecked` seems to get triggered a massive amount of times and I'm afraid of performance issues.

What might be going on here, and what I can do to fix this strange issue?

Comment: Is it how you really dispatch that action? Maybe you dispatch it from callback or something? Because it looks like you dispatching and action outside of NgZone that is why it's not being checked.

Comment: What's the `selectors.loaderOverlaySelector`? Instead of assigning the state to `loaderOverlay$`, try subscribing instead to see what you get `this.store.pipe(
  select(selectors.loaderOverlaySelector).subscribe(value => { console.log(value) })
);`

Comment: @AmirArbabian yes that is how I am dispatching my action, can you suggest another way to dispatch my actionn?

Comment: Ok then I'm curious now where you use myFunction()? 
Is it from template of child component?

Comment: @AmirArbabian I am using that function inside a child component. Gets called after clicking a button

Comment: @DzhavatUshev I could do that but doesnt the `async` pipe accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Please add action, store and effect code so we can see the big picture, if you can make a stackblitz example that would be awesome :)

Comment: @cup_of Yes, the `async` pipe does that but just for debugging purposes. After you figure out how to solve the problem, you can clean up.

Comment: I'd also put `{{ (loaderOverlay$ | async) | json }}` right before the `<div *ngif="(loaderOverlay$ | async)"></div>` to see if the value changes in the template. The next thing will be to use `tap` to see if the value changes in the observable. Or maybe use `tap` to run `this.changeDetector.detectChanges();` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @DzhavatUshev ok i can try that, thanks!

Comment: @FRECIA there is no effect and the store is a simple updating of the store. action -> store value gets updated

Comment: Why don't you subscribe to the store and then detect changes?
`this.store.pipe( select(selectors.loaderOverlaySelector).subscribe(() => this.changeDetector.detectChanges());`

Comment: @Srdjan that defeats the purpose of the store in combination with the async pipe

Comment: In the store did you update the data correctly like clone the objects which are changed ? Cause from what I see here it looks correct but the store mingt not notify loaderOverlay$ that a change was made

Comment: `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` isn't the same of `this.changeDetection.detach()`! You haven't to trigger change detection manually if you use the `OnPush`, it's something that only regards the input properties. Are you sure you didn't go out from zone? Did you use some not-angular component?

Comment: have you tried the as sintax? `<div *ngif="(loaderOverlay$ | async) as display"><div *ngIf="display">Show whatever</div></div>` taken from [here](https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe)

Comment: I had this behaviour when I was migrating from AngularJS to angular2+ with Ng-Metadata. However, what solved it was: (In your `@Component({selector:"",templateUrl:"", encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None})` use the `ViewEncapsulation.None` option instead. This prevents angular from updating itself all the time if you have a `<style>` tag in your html. Also, It might be because u want to have a one-*TIME* binding instead of one-*WAY* binding (google it). Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Does your `loaderOverlay$` emitted value evaluate to `true`? I created a similar code (as you described) on stackblitz and I can't seem to be able to reproduce the bug you encounter. It's either a bug that was fixed in angular/ngrx, or the value you are emitting does not evaluate to true (the select is not good and returns undefined or something). Try tapping the observable and logging the results.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-update?file=src/app/app.component.css

**Later Edit:**

As Cristian Traina pointed out in the comments, `markForCheck` (from inside the async pipe) doesn't trigger the change detection when it's called from outside angular. As a fix, you can use a zone scheduler in your pipe, or detect where the change comes from and patch that area to trigger a change detection inside angular (since there may be problems in other areas of your app).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-zone-scheduler?activeTab=readme

```
public constructor(
  @Inject(ZoneScheduler)
  private readonly zoneScheduler: SchedulerLike,
) {}

this.loaderOverlay$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(selectors.loaderOverlaySelector),
  observeOn(this.zoneScheduler),
);
```

or you can just `tick` the `appRef`

```
public constructor(
  private appRef: ApplicationRef,
) {}

this.loaderOverlay$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(selectors.loaderOverlaySelector),
  tap(_ => this.appRef.tick()),
);
```

Comment: As I said in my comment, it's probably a problem related to Zone

Comment: @CristianTraìna I doubt it... I added the dispatch outside Zone in the stackblitz example and it works fine.

Comment: @CristianTraìna you're right... I expected markForCheck to run inside angular even if it's called outside of it...

Comment: Your solution is ok, but sounds like a workaround. Observables are zone-friendly, so they should trigger change detection by themselves. The real problem is elsewhere, maybe he's using google maps somewhere, and that's also the reason why you can't reproduce the bug in your snippet

Comment: @CristianTraìna I was able to reproduce it using setTimeout ouside angular. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-update?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Uhm sorry, but it still works with `setTimeout` (the first button), instead it doesn't work with the second button. Exactly as expected

Answer (score 3):

From your example, it seems like the `onPush` strategy is not being used correctly. The `onPush` strategy means that the component will not necessarily update if its `@inputs` are not changing, even if variables are being updated in the component. From what I can gather in your example, the parent component's `@input` references are not changing, which means that the change detection is not happening as you expect.

To fix this I would suggest updating the parent component (which is subscribing to the store updates) to either use `defaultStrategy` or manually call `markForCheck()` as needed to trigger an update.

Comment: He is using the async pipe, that implicitly does the markForCheck(). So IMO this couldn't be the reason

Comment: @LlorençPujolFerriol if he is not using the async function on the inputs to the parent, i don't think markForCheck() would be implicitly called. if the inputs to the parent are not changing, nothing will call markForCheck

Comment: @JusMalcolm if you look into the async pipe code it does call markForCheck when a new event comes over the Observable.  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/72c36956deb30198c0ffba359c37374128588c53/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L143

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. By editing an input field, the results were to be fetched from the backend and shown in a list. The list did not get updated unless I hovered over or clicked somewhere else.

I fixed it by adding a manual change detection after fetching the data from the backend.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

fetchData.subscribe(results => {
   AddResultsToStore(results);
   this.cd.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: This will not help! The `async` pipe already marks the component as dirty when the observable emits a new value... Most likely his events are coming outside of the angular zone.

Comment: Could be! I don't know his exact setup. I just wrote it down incase it helps with his issue. It helped in one specific similar issue in my code, I don't recommend to use this after every call ofcourse.